# TE:No route matches error when trying to use RSpec and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to write a test using RSpec and Capybara, however, I'm always getting the following error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/semead/assets/application-7a2cf02623b8feb6b939ae72b917f262a79b289d0bf90f0a932f8eb031fe5ef6.js"
```

In some cases the same error occurs with the `application.css` asset. I tried to use capybara-webkit and selenium-webdriver, but the outcome it's the same.

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'support/factory_girl'
...
```

**specs/spec_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'support/factory_girl'
require 'capybara/rspec'
...
```

**spec/features/user_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'    
RSpec.feature "Registering a new user", js: true do
  scenario "fill the registration form" do
    visit "/participantes/new"
    @user = build(:user)
...
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is the full error message:

```
Failures:

  1) Registering a new user filling the registration form
     Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"

     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/semead/assets/application-f01fee28086ae8e064a7eda175e05dd4423d0429269ec94c142dc12b2eb6768d.css"
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:66:in `block in call'
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:43:in `call'
     # /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Capybara::ElementNotFound:
     #   Unable to find css ".select2-container"
     #   /home/jalerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:44:in `block in find'
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is my `config/application.rb`, which I set `config.relative_url_root = '/semead'`

**config/application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Semead
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.relative_url_root = '/semead'
    config.i18n.default_locale = 'pt-BR'
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :trabalhos do
    get 'prazo_encerrado', on: :collection
  end
  resources :minicursos do
    resources :inscricoes
  end
  namespace :admin do
    resources :participantes do
      get 'aprovar_nota_empenho'
    end
    resources :organizadores
    resources :trabalhos do
      get 'avaliar'
      resources :avaliacoes, controller: 'avaliacoes_trabalhos'
    end
    resources :minicursos do
      resources :avaliacoes, controller: 'avaliacoes_minicursos'
    end
  end

  resources :sessions
  resources :participantes do
    get 'pagar'
  end
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'participantes#new'
...
```

Comment: Why is there a subfolder (`semead`) in front of `/assets` in the URL that it's trying to hit?

Comment: Hi @ChrisPeters, thanks for your comment! The subfolder `/semead` is needed because I need to run this app into `http://eventos.ifrn.edu.br/semead`

Comment: Show your routes.rb and whether or how you've told your app to mount at /semead

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ThomasWalpole! I just updated the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not confirmed this, but as an educated guess - I believe `config.relative_url_root` only affects route generation but not route processing.  When testing, Capybara mounts the app under test at '/' - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rails.rb, which would mean the requests to /semead/... won't get routed correctly.  The easiest solution to this is probably to se `config.relative_url_root` to '/' in config/environments/test.rb

Note that just redefining Capybara.app to mount the app at /semead probably won't work because Capybara installs middleware with a couple of actions it needs to work.

Comment: Yes, apparently that's the problem. I moved the `config.relative_url_root` to the `environments/test.rb`, and the problem with the reference to the assets was solved. Thanks!

Comment: @JalersonLima You're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) so the question gets marked as answered